# Check if any database table has any rows

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, linq-query-syntax

I am trying to understand how to check if any table in my db has data using entity framework. I can check for one table but how can I check for all tables at once? DO we have any option with ef6?

```
using (var db = new CreateDbContext())
{
    if(!db.FirstTable.Any())
    {
        // The table is empty
    }
}
```

Any pointers on how to loop through entities would be helpful.

Comment: You would have to loop through all tables and check them one at a time.

Comment: Thanks for pointer. Just checking if there is any build in method in entityframework which does that to decrease time and improve performance.

Comment: I don't know EF but I doubt anything like that exists because it couldn't actually help with performance. The sql engine has to query for each table.

Comment: If that's something you needs, it would be best to create trigger that updates a table that contains that information.  That way you have 1 request to see if any table has data.

Comment: @SeanLange any way to update statistics and use this? Got to be better than if exists or something ya?

Comment: @ErikPhilips you would have to add that trigger to every single table in the database. And then it would just firing all the time which seems to be a huge waste of resources. My guess is they are just trying to see if the database is a fresh install or not.

Comment: @scsimon yes I think the query I posted should work, and it is way faster than a loop looking at each table or something along those lines.

Comment: Nice @SeanLange i was looking around for something like this.

Answer (score 5):

Here is one way you could do this with t-sql. This should be lightning fast on most systems. This returned in less than a second on our ERP database. It stated 421 billion rows in more than 15,000 partition stats.

```
select sum(p.row_count)
from sys.dm_db_partition_stats p
join sys.objects o on o.object_id = p.object_id
where o.type not in ('S', 'IT') --excludes system and internal tables.
```

Answer (score 3):

Similar to @SeanLange, but shows schema name and table name for tables without any rows.

```
SELECT  Distinct OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(p.object_id) AS [Schema], 
        OBJECT_NAME(p.object_id) AS [Table]
FROM    sys.partitions p
        INNER JOIN sys.indexes i 
            ON p.object_id = i.object_id
            AND p.index_id = i.index_id
WHERE   OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(p.object_id) != 'sys'
        And p.Rows = 0    
ORDER BY [Schema], [Table]
```

Comment: Change `And p.Rows = 0` to `And p.Rows != 0` to see all tables that do have content.